# Unity WebGL player just shows black screen

Tags: unity, unity-webgl

I built my Unity project with WebGL. After load the resources, I can hear the music and player sounds(movements etc), but it just display black screen only. I found some similar situation in google, but couldn't find the way to fix.

Here's the console result:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=14Uhd6SBbDHdPN39TurY9H7QPGhPLfb_X

Used Unity 2018.2.1f1, tested with Chrome 73.0.3683.86.

Comment: Please embed the examples or images you want to show in your question itself. Do not link to an off-site file storage service.

Comment: Today I recreate whole things with Unity 2017, and now it works. Even there is FXAA, still works. I think this problem causing from 2018.x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with 2017.x works fine. Might be issue of 2018.x or higher.

Answer (score 0):

It says "Missing shader in Camera (FXAA)" So guessing you have some issues with your anti aliasing post processing.

Look at "Anti-Aliasing" and "WebGL 2.0 support" in https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-graphics.html

Or maybe try to verify that the post processes you have setup on the camera are not missing: https://forum.unity.com/threads/missing-shader-in-main-camera-error.113929/

Comment: This. My experience porting an industry game to WebGL is that WebGL has many many things that don't work, some of which aren't even documented. Try a few hundred sounds on chrome on mac. Guess what? Sound will crash and die. Unity's Audio management doesn't work at all in WebGL, meaning every sound you play, is heard until you overload the max sounds. For WebGL, start as simple as possible, build OFTEN, so you can isolate the change that messed it up. WebGL is a massive hassle

Comment: Thanks, so I just removed FXAA, but still black screen of death. There's no post processing stuffs anymore.

Comment: Hmm, have you tested if it runs from an other source than localhost? maybe just run from your local ip or if you have a web server where you can deploy. I have experienced issues with restrictions when testing code in chrome locally before. I either use firefox or upload to a server. "Failed to execute 'put' on 'IDBObjectStore': A WebAssembly.Module can not be serialized for storage." could sound like a security issue.

Comment: I'm always testing with server made by Node.js. All resources loaded properly. I leaved the comment in my question, I did exactly samething with 2017.x and it works now. Probably something wrong in 2018.x version.